# foreign key constraint fails when drop table from database

Tags: mysql

I've created 3 tables using the query bellow. But when I try to drop the `LOANACCOUNT` table I receive an error:

**Error:**

> Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

**Create tables queries:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE LOANACCOUNT
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LOANACCOUNTTYPE VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    CREATIONDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT LOAN_ACCOUNT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ACCOUNTID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    TRANSACTIONTYPE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TRANSACTION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY LOANACCOUNT_FK (ACCOUNTID) REFERENCES LOANACCOUNT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE INSTALLMENT
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ACCOUNTID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    DUEDATE DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT INSTALLMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY LOANACCOUNT_FK (ACCOUNTID) REFERENCES LOANACCOUNT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Drop table query:**

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOANACCOUNT;
```

I know that there is something wrong with my foreign keys, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Yup, Because LOANACCOUNT is linked to by Both the other tables. You will have to drop the other two tables first, then you can drop LOANACCOUNT

Comment: @RiggsFolly But is there a way to drop all foreign keys linked to the table that I want to drop? One command I mean, not to drop them separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rigg Suggested need to drop other table before dropping `LOANACCOUNT`.

(i.e.) Parent table can't be drop unless there is no child linked.

For time being you can disable foreign key check and then drop those tables.

```
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOANACCOUNT;
SET SESSION foreign_key_checks = 1;
```